# i want to generate multiple builds at shot with different package names for the same project in Android

Tags: android

wants to write ant script manually for my project in Android, without using android update command. Please provide any sample ant script code or any URL's which has samples...

The reason is "wants to generate multiple builds at one shot with different package names for the same project(is it possible really with one ant script and with same project? )"

Any Answers would be welcome..!

Comment: I strongly encourage you to move to [Gradle for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). Depending upon your criteria for "multiple builds at one shot with different package names for the same project", it may work for you without modification. Gradle for Android is replacing Ant; I would not recommend investing serious time in customizing Android Ant scripts anymore.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion .. CommonsWare. I will look at that Gradle.